# expand DIV with contents when this contents are absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to put two divs over each other like layers of some ontent
and because I dont know what content size will be,I gave tow divs POSITION:ABSOLUTE to set thew twise at the top left of their container

**the problem is:** the container dosent expand with absolute divs
I tried some jquery to set height of the child to the parent, but because the absolute child div doesnt have width or height from the beginning, the code didnt affect

```
$("div.selectionTabs.inner").css("height",$("div.selectionTabs.inner>div.productsTab.under").height()+"px");
```

Comment: You might want to consider ``position:relative`` than ``position:absolute``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function placeElementOver(e1,e2){
 e1.style.position = "absolute";
 e1.style.left = e2.getClientRects()[0].left;
 e1.style.top = e2.getClientRects()[0].top;
 e1.style.width = e2.clientWidth;
 e1.style.height = e2.clientHeight;
}
```

Then just call

```
placeElementOver(div2,div1);
```

in some init function.